# Is it possible for a particle to have an infinite lifespan in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, particles

I'm trying to do an experiment where the user creates particles when they touch the screen, and then the particles just stay in place, only dying in collision. I'm wondering if it would be possible to do this in a way where the particles have an infinite lifespan? I feel like I've done this in Unity before, but never in SceneKit.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the universe is scheduled to end in approximately 5 billion years.

Comment: Well, there go all my singularity dreams 

Comment: Can you just use this property and set it to something like 5 billion years? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnparticlesystem/1523575-particlelifespan

Comment: I suppose so, but shouldn't there be some option to just turn particle death off? You can remove particle death on collision

Comment: Might a value of `-1` work? I've seen some engines use that to represent a lifespan of infinity. Or maybe [`CGFloat.infinity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgfloat/1454161-infinity).

Comment: Test it, and you may be able to answer your own question.

Comment: I've used -1 in game engines before. Unfortunately in Scenekit this just causes it to do nothing. I was, however, get it to live for up to 25k seconds, which is well beyond the amount of time that I would expect users to play with the project.

Comment: Would +inf break things?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to completely eliminate particle death, but you can set the particle life span to an outrageously high number (20,000 seconds is pretty close to the upper limit of the safe zone) well beyond what would be expected for user interaction on an iOS game.